# How to use a third-party library in a taskKey?

Tags: scala, sbt

I want to use third party library in a `taskKey` in the .Scala/.sbt project files.

My problem is when I try to import the file I get a compilation error.

My goal is simple I want to add a task key that execute some logic using sbt cli, I have tried an example using [sbt command line application](http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.13/docs/Command-Line-Applications.html), but it doesn't meet my need because I need to package the application to test the code.

So how could I import dependencies into sbt cli during the load phase?

Example:

```
val customTaskKey = TaskKey[Unit]("customTaskKey", "Runs customTaskKey")
lazy val myProjectSettings: Seq[Setting[_]] = Seq(
  customTaskKey :={

    val instance : ThirdPartLibraryClass()
    //             ^
    //            Symbol not found : compilation error
  }
)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add the dependency the normal way, but in the `my-project/project/plugin.sbt` file instead of `my-project/build.sbt` :

```
libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  "thirdparty" % "library" % "1.0"
)
```

If your project is `foo`, `foo/project` is another SBT project, which builds the SBT build for the foo project. So configuration done in `foo/project` folder applies to the build for `foo`, rather than to `foo` itself.

Comment: Tahnk you for your help.